# I am not able to set Git path in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I have installed Git on my CentOS 7 and installed Jenkins
When I give my Git Path in the Source code management section, I am getting the below error. Can someone please error

[image]

I have already googled and tried many commands ( I am pretty new to Linux commands) but didn't help
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Jenkins is unable to execute the script [because it does not have adequate permissions for the temporary directory](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003082887-Jenkins-with-Git-Client-needs-permission-on-Temporary-directory).

Give the user running Jenkins access to read and write to `/tmp`.

Comment: Can you please give me some steps.. as I told I am new to this CentOS

Comment: It would help to know which commands you've tried before.

Comment: i gave the permission to tmp folder with the below command
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /tmp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like error is in Repository URL. [image: Example]

Take url from your repo like in the picture and paste to jenkins job config.